# Split screen not working

Tags: windows-7

I have been using a split screen perfectly fine for the last year, suddenly today, what was no 1 is no longer working. It is black. If i turn it off and back on, the display from no 2 shows very briefly, then goes black again. I have tried to make these extended and applied but to no avail. I have also tried swapping the cables but have the same result.
DianeI am not computer savvy so simple answers please.

Comment: Does display 2 go into power-saving mode or is it just black? Secondary displays show just a black color when Windows shows it's lock screen. Are you able to test display 1 on a different computer?

Comment: When i turn the screen off then back on, you get a brief view of the tabs displayed but then it goes straight back to black. Screen 2 now when i identify the screens, shows 1/2 instead of monitor 1 and monitor 2 separately. I have yet to see if it works elsewhere but will try that later as have another tower in storage.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cheri4741's answer in the link: [My split screen stopped working on windows 7](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/my-split-screen-stopped-working-on-windows-7/5315e269-e942-49f5-87f2-339991cd8aa4)

We can try the following steps:

1. Click `Start`, `Control Panel`
2. Click `Ease of Access` and click `Ease of Access Center`
3. Click `Make it easier to focus on tasks`
4. Place a checkmark near the following option:
   `Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen`
5. Click `OK`, and close the Ease of Access Center

Comment: I have just tried this cheri4741 but has not worked. Thanks though.